# What does "Visualforce Remoting: Context incomplete" mean?

Tags: visualforce, force.com

When using javascript remoting in a VisualForce page, I get a warning in my javascript console, "Visualforce Remoting: Context incomplete".

What does it mean, and what are the implications?

Answer (score 0):

This message means that Visualforce remoting internals were not added to the remoting request.

Are you still seeing this Javascript console message?  If you were seeing this message and your remoting transactions were working as expected, it's likely you were seeing an innocuous bug that has been fixed.  If you're seeing this warning and your transaction is failing, please post to the Visualforce message boards giving details (https://bitly.com/).  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen it recently, and it didn't seem to cause any problems.  I guess it was the bug.